# how can i get the max count voted pictures from my vote table

Tags: mysql, laravel, count, laravel-5

```
SELECT userfbimages_id, count( * )
FROM votes
GROUP BY userfbimages_id 
HAVING count( * ) >= ALL (SELECT count( * )
                          FROM votes
                          GROUP BY userfbimages_id)
```

I tried this query but I dont know how  to do it in laravel5.2 !!
I tried

> $topim=Vote::where(SELECT userfbimages_id, count(*) FROM votes GROUP
>   BY userfbimages_id  HAVING count(*) >= ALL (SELECT count(*) FROM votes
>   GROUP BY userfbimages_id));

returns Null

Comment: still looking for a solution !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who look for an answer for my question i found a solution `

```
>     return $this->model
>                       ->where('seen','=', 1)
>                       ->with('votes')
>                       -sortby(function($top){
>                       return $top->votes->count();}, SORT_REGULAR, true);
```

`this works with sortby and with a subquery !! but for a pagination you should change this with lefjoin statement :`

```
                return $this->model
                    ->where('seen','=', 1)
                    ->leftJoin('votes','votes.userfbimages_id','=','userfbimages.id')
                    ->selectRaw('userfbimages.*, count(votes.userfbimages_id) AS `count`')
                    ->groupBy('userfbimages.id')
                    ->orderBy('count','DESC')
                    ->paginate($n);
`
```

i found the solution so i hope it would be helpfull for you

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the star.

count(*) should be all you need to make that query valid!

Comment: QLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'count( * ) FROM votes 
GROUP BY userfbimages_id 
HAVING count( * ) >= ALL (SELECT count( * ) FROM votes GROUP BY userfbimages_id' inconnu dans where clause (SQL: select * from `votes` where `count( * ) FROM votes 
GROUP BY userfbimages_id 
HAVING count( * ) >= ALL (SELECT count(*) FROM votes GROUP BY userfbimages_id` is null)

Comment: To confirm, your query works direct on MySQL but your Laravel structured query does not work? If that is the case then perhaps you should just execute it as a raw SQL statement within Laravel? This is certainly possible in Doctrine but unsure about how Laravel/(eloquent?) works..

Comment: My query works well when i run it on my sql !! the problem is with laravel i dont know how to do this :(